# Do we even need the "quran" tag?

Tags: discussion, tag

The [quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran) tag is the single most popular tag on the site (as of this post, it's holding 192 questions).

Its use, however, does not seem to be coherent.  Flipping through the first page of questions, it seems that they can be classified according to the following categories:

1. Asking about the interpretation of an *ayah* (i.e. [tafseer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tafseer)).
2. Seeking a particular *ayah* from the Qur'an (i.e. [source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification)).
3. Expecting an answer backed by Qur'anic references.
4. Asking any question at all in which the Qur'an might be relevant.
5. Asking about the Qur'an itself.

The first two, obviously, have much better tags which clearly describe the nature of the question; these questions are often (but not always) tagged with both.  The third use, to me, is better suited for the body of the question itself; the tag in this case is merely a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), rather than describing the content of the question in any meaningful way.  And the fourth use just renders the tag worthless, as it would apply to pretty much every question on this site (might as well just have an [islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam) tag in that case).

The third and fourth categories, sadly, seem to be both the most prevalent, and the least useful, of those listed.

The fifth option, to me, is the only constructive use of the tag (even then, a lot of them may be better categorized under [mushaf](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mushaf)).  However, questions *about the actual Qur'an itself* are vastly outnumbered by those in the first four categories.

**What should we do about the [quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran) tag?  Is it even necessary, and if so, how should it be used?**

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that [quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran) tag should be completely removed, rather it should be used on questions that are directly asking about something in the Quran like [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/what-does-the-quran-say-about-shrine-worshiping) and [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/is-the-quran-incorrect-about-jewish-beliefs).  But things asking for Tafseer like [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/understanding-the-first-revealed-verse-of-quran-is-man-created-from-a-clot-of-b), should only be under the [tafseer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tafseer) tag.

What I am basically trying to say is, if a question is specifically asking about or what is in the Quran, than it should be tagged with the [quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran) tag.  And each question should be re-tagged according to it's subject, whether it is asking for tafseer, or language/Arabic clarification and so on.

Comment: I agree with this -- I think this tag probably needs a cleanup more than a deletion.

Comment: Yes, questions about [tag:tafseer] do not need to be tagged with [tag:quran]. We should update their tag wikies to explain how and for what these tags can be used.

Answer (score 2):

I think, we need to be very specific, and coherent on our usage of tags. I think we need to do a major cleanup on [quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran) and it should only be applied to category 5 in your question. For example, these are suitable questions to be tagged with [quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran);

- [How was the order of the Qur'an decided?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/838/how-was-the-order-of-the-quran-decided)
- [How do we know that the Qur'an has never been changed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-do-we-know-that-the-quran-has-never-been-changed)

Moreover, we should apply [mushaf](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mushaf) to questions that are about written for of the Qur'an. Currently, we have 6 questions tagged with [mushaf](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mushaf) and all of those questions are good example of usage of this tag.

We should also make separation between [quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran) and [tafseer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tafseer) and [tajweed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tajweed).

And, categories 3 and 4 should be cleaned, and [quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran) should be removed from them.

**tl;dr**: We still need [quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran), but tag needs major cleanup before it can become useful. We should also be very specific about our tag usage.